# Hook error for React while grabbing data from Unsplash

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-infinite-scroll-component

I am fairly new to programming and this is my first question here. I am trying to grab the images from the unsplash to create a scrollable page with unlimited random images. I keep getting hook error on
setImages([...images, ...res.data]);
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { UnsplashImage } from './randomImages/UnsplashImage';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';


const Landing = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchImages();
    }, [])
  
    const fetchImages = (count = 10) => {
      const apiRoot = "https://api.unsplash.com";
  
      axios
      .get(`${apiRoot}/photos/random?{clientid}&count=${count}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setImages([...images, ...res.data]);
      });
  };

    return (
        <div className="Landing">
            <style>{ 'body {background-color: #5e90be'}</style>
            <img id = "x" src= "example_images/logo.png"
                alt=""></img>
            <h5>Welcome to Photodex</h5>
            <div className="image-grid">
              {images.map(image => (
                    <UnsplashImage
                      url={image.urls.regular}
                      key={image.id}
                      alt={image.description}
                    />
              ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

export default Landing;

UnsplashImage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Img = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
`;

export const UnsplashImage = ({ url, key }) => {
  return (
    <Img key={key} src={url} alt="" />
  )
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
> 46 |        setImages([...images, ...res.data]);

Comment: What version of react are you using?

Comment: I think it is React@17.0.2

Comment: Code is perfect. confirm that you don't have multiple reactjs versions of different React & React DOM versions in the package.json.

Comment: This is the different versions I have in package.json 
    "random-image-unsplash": "^1.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

Comment: Yeah nothing looks wrong to me so it must be something with your packages